# Ignoring the pole?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the integral $$\int^{2 \pi}_0 \frac{z}{z+2} dz$$ where $$|z|=3$$

I parametrise the integral and get $$\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{9 ie^{2i\theta}}{3e^{i\theta}+2}$$
and this gives the required answer of $$-4i\pi$$

My question is do we not have to worry about the pole that occurs at $z=-2$?

Comment: No, you don't have $\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{z}{z+2}\; dz$, you have $\displaystyle \oint_C \dfrac{z}{z+2}\; dz$ where $C$ is the (positively oriented, I presume) circle $|z|=3$.  $z$ doesn't go anywhere near $0$ or $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're explicitly parametrising it, the pole doesn't enter into consideration because the pole is not on the contour.  If you were to do the integral using residues, you would say: the pole $-2$ is inside the contour, and the residue of your function there is $-2$, so the result is $2\pi i (-2) = -4 \pi i$.

Comment: What does "not on the contour" mean?

Comment: The contour is the circle $|z|=3$ that you're integrating over.  $|-2| \ne 3$ so $-2$ is not on the contour.

Comment: So if their was a pole at z=3, it is on the contour then what would you do?

Comment: Then you'd have an improper integral that does not converge.  It would exist at most in the Cauchy principal value sense.

Answer (score 0):

No, if there were no poles in the interior of your curve your integral will be 0. You can always integrate around a pole. If there are no poles everything is 0.

Comment: So how do we integrate around a pole? In my working out I feel have seemingly ignored the specific pole?

Comment: Your curve doesn't contain the pole. The curve turns around your pole. There are no problem. Which is your definition of a curve integral?